# How to turn off PHP + MySQL error formatting

Tags: error-reporting, php

How to turn off PHP error formatting for getting only plain text? This should also affect MySQL related functions.

I want to get plain text, instead of structured HTML error message.

UPDATE

AS **Artefact2** suggested I need to modify php.ini file, so

```
ini_set('html_errors', false);
```

does the trick if I need it in realtime.

Comment: @NAVEED, you should know that there's a delay between question and acception. I have to wait 7 more minutes

Comment: I know that but I wanted to confirm that you also know :) Its OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors

Just set html_errors to "Off" in your php.ini.